# Understanding the need for explicitly adding () to get an evaluation

Tags: python, python-2.7

This works.

```
class Bob(object):
    def __init__(self, xvals):
        self.xvals = xvals
    def get_xmax(self):
        return max(self.xvals)

bob = Bob([3, 1, 2])
print bob.get_xmax()    # returns 3

bob.xvals = [-3, -1, -2]
print bob.get_xmax()    # returns -1
```

This doesn't because `max()` is evaluated only once during instantiation.

```
class Bob(object):
    def __init__(self, xvals):
        self.xvals = xvals
        self.xmax  = max(self.xvals)  # evaluated during instantiation

bob = Bob([3, 1, 2])
print bob.xmax    # returns 3

bob.xvals = [-3, -1, -2]
print bob.xmax    # still returns 3, not -1
```

Is there a simple (and pythonic) way to get `bob.xmax` to return the current maximum with out the `()` or is that the point - potentially expensive operations should require `()` as a reminder that you are asking for more than just a reference to an object?

Comment: You can introduce getter and setter methods and update `xmax` in the setter method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`property`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property):

```
class Bob(object):
    def __init__(self, xvals):
        self.xvals = xvals

    @property
    def xmax(self):  # called when `xmax` attribute is accessed
        return max(self.xvals)
```

---

```
>>> bob = Bob([3, 1, 2])
>>> bob.xmax
3
>>> 
>>> bob.xvals = [-3, -1, -2]
>>> bob.xmax
-1
```

Alternatively, you can also define setter property, so that `xmax` is calculated only once.

```
class Bob(object):
    def __init__(self, xvals):
        self.xmax = None
        self.xvals = xvals

    @property
    def xvals(self):
        return self._xvals

    @xvals.setter
    def xvals(self, values):
        self._xvals = values
        self.xmax = max(values)
```

CAUTION: setter approach will not work if you do something like: `bob.xvals.append(999)` because it doesn't trigger the setter method invokation.

Comment: @uhoh, I don't understand what you mean. BTW, I added another example that use setter.

Comment: I understand what you're doing now, this is really *really* great, thanks!